# MVC3 data annotation for regex incorrectly firing

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have an Entity Frameworks POCO that has a property defined like this:

```
[RegularExpression(ValidationHelper.RegularExpressionForDateOnly)]
public virtual DateTime LastBuildDate { get; set; }
```

Where the constant is defined like this:

```
public const String RegularExpressionForDateOnly = 
    @"^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$";
```

I got that regex right from OWASP: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Validation_Regex_Repository

Now, on the MVC3 view, I have:

```
<tr>
<td class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastBuildDate)
</td>
<td class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastBuildDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastBuildDate)
</td>
</tr>
```

When I try to put a date in the format of "05/30/2012" or "5/30/2012", it fails validation (client and server-side). If I manually try that regular expression, that regular expression SHOULD allow those formats. However, when the MVC3 view is validating with it, it fails validation.

What other reason would there be for the MVC to fail this regex validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know enough about regex to tell you exactly what your doing wrong, but when it comes to MVC3 validators, I definitely recommend the [Data Annotations Extension](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/) you can find it on Nuget too.
It adds a bunch of validation attributes including date validation.

Comment: First thanks - I've never run across that before! It is something I can use on the "server side" (as my model is in a different assembly), but I can't use any of the MVC3 parts of it because: "error CS1577: Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'WebActivator' does not have a strong name"

Comment: Actually - that did it, the validation does work/fail as expected even without the additional MVC3 piece (whatever that is). I assume there must be something goofy in that OWASP regex? Who knows. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: no problem. Im not sure what the MVC3 piece is thats missing, but I think theres also a download link for the non MVC3 version that should work without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Just to mention that you can use RemoteValidation attribute ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute(v=vs.98).aspx ) when you need to write special kind of validation, it's simple as you don't need to make your custom DataAnnotation adapter and then register your adapter in global.asax.

Here's an examle:

Your model:

```
[Remote("ValidateSpecialNumber", HttpMethod="Post", 
    ErrorMessage = "You're number isn't special.")]
public int SpecialNumber { get; set; }
```

Action which is called on validation:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ValidateSpecialNumber(int SpecialNumber)
{
    // validate your number here and return True if validated
    return Json(true);
}
```

I'm pointing this out because few people knows about it.

Regards

Comment: This is cool - I didn't get how that attribute worked before, thanks!